# CartoDB - inserting polygons

Tags: postgis, carto, php, curl

I am new to using PostGIS and CartoDB, and I am doing some test SQL inserts into both using PHP.  I've had no problem with points, but polygons are proving to be a bit tricky - my SQL insert works just fine with PostGIS on my local server (or so it seems to me), but it does not work with CartoDB.

Here's my PHP...

```
<?php
    $cartodb_username = "***";
    $api_key = "***";

    $cartoDBsql = "INSERT INTO polygon_test (poly_geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571,-71.1776820268866 42.3903701743239,-71.1776063012595 42.3903825660754,-71.1775826583081 42.3903033653531,-71.1776585052917 42.3902909739571))', 4326))";

    $ch = curl_init( "https://".$cartodb_username.".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql" );
    $query = http_build_query(array('q'=>$cartoDBsql,'api_key'=>$api_key));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result_not_parsed = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

This code does insert points correctly, though, for example using:

```
$cartoDBsql = "INSERT INTO geometry_test ( the_geom ) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)', 4326))";
```

... but polygons do not work.  I imagine that I am not formatting the data in my insert statement correctly, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I've searched the CartoDB documentation and can't find an example of an ST_GeomFromText insert for a polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_GeomFromText takes a WKT parameter, which is a text string of WKT. However, you can't use database parameters to format text within an SQL statement. (You would need to use PHP's text formatting utilities, like sprintf, but I don't think this is a good approach).

A better way is to use PostGIS geometry constructors that take numeric parameters, e.g.

```
$cartoDBsql = "INSERT INTO geometry_test (the_geom) VALUES
               (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($longitude, $latitude), 4326))";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!  This hipped me to ST_MakePolygon, which I was able to follow to this resource: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/spatialdb/node/1970 which had the syntax I needed - about halfway down the page.  Dig the Zoidberg!